# Watir and javascript pop-up window

Tags: watir

I have just started to learn Watir... I'm stuck with this:

I try to make Watir click (and read the content) of this javascript popup window:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert

My Watir code looks like this:

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.start "www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert"
b.maximize
b.frame(:name, "view").button(:text, "Show alert box").click
b.javascript_dialog.button('OK').click
```

..But it's not working, Watir is not clicking "OK" button on the popup Window.

I know that Watir-Webdriver can handle popup windows ("browser.alert.ok"), but can "classic" IE-only Watir do this (without any complicated hacks, using AutoIt / Sikuli etc)?

**EDIT:** I was able to remove popup window completely with this line:

```
b.frame(:name, "view").execute_script("window.alert = function() {}")
```

Better than nothing, now tests will not hang to popup windows, but I still can't confirm / read popup windows...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after Watir clicks the button to open the javascript dialog, it is waiting for something that it never gets.

The solution is to click the button with a `click_no_wait`. Try this instead:

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.start "www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert"
b.maximize
b.frame(:name, "view").button(:text, "Show alert box").click_no_wait
b.javascript_dialog.button('OK').click
```

Update: Just noticed that this documented on the Watir wiki - http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript+Pop+Ups (see first example).

Comment: Yes this might be the solution... Only one "small" problem: Using "click_no_wait" crashes Ruby completely, Windows shuts it down and wants to send error report to Microsoft... (I'm using XP SP3, Ruby 1.9.3p194, Watir 3.0.0.)

Comment: I was using Win7, Ruby 1.8.7, Watir 3.0.0.

Comment: After downgrading Ruby to 1.9.2 it's no longer crashing on "click_no_wait". However, Watir still refuses to click popup window.

Comment: Set $DEBUG=true just before #click_no_wait - do you see any error messages then?

Comment: As I just said, there is no longer error with "click_no_wait". It was fixed by installing older Ruby version (1.9.2). But line `b.javascript_dialog.button('OK').click` still does not work.

Comment: @JarmoPertman, the exception I saw for both this and for file fields (with Ruby 1.9.3) appears to be the same as that reported in [Issue 31 of the rautomation](https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation/issues/31c)